# Running a Windows 2008 server trial on Linux

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, virtualization

I want to run a trial of Windows Server 2008 on a Linux machine. The single official trial I have found is [an exe file which should contain a VHD image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9040a4be-c3cf-44a5-9052-a70314452305&displaylang=en).

Is there any way of getting the trial to run on a Linux host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ISO via [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx).

Comment: _No idea_ why I didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i gotted from following locations

http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/E/C/DEC012DC-C822-43C2-88EA-D53234930393/Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20Enterprise%20Evaluation%20(Full%20Edition).exe

Comment: This question is for Linux, I can't do anything with an exe file.

Comment: that i understood i wanted now which distro are using

Answer (score 0):

you could use vmware-player on your linux-host and install the previous mentioned iso-files / *.exe in it.

Good luck.

Peace

Ice